# Rails for enterprise solutions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out what technology to use to develop an enterprise solution.

I like Rails and want an excuse to use it - but it seems to me that not many developers/companies write enterprise solutions with it.

A very brief description for brevity:

Agents on endpoints within the enterprise will send some information to the server periodically, the server (on premise) will store the information and provide some alerts, reports and administration options to the admin users.

- Has anyone here tried it (writing an enterprise solution with Rails)?
- How was it accepted by the IT teams of the different customers?
- Are they willing to setup a Rails server on Linux boxes or did you have to deploy on Windows or use a virtualization?
- Resellers and channels - were they able to handle such a deployment?

I Googled "Rails for Enterprise Solutions" and judging by the results (only a few - and not too relevant) the situation doesn't look promising.

I'd appreciate any help here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've done some small deployments similar to what your describing. At the end of the day, rails is a web app framework so it really only makes sense for a web-based solution.

As far as hosting on your own servers, Ubuntu is doing some cool things that would make deploying something like what you're talking about a bit easier. Specifically, checkout their OpenStack platform and Juju in particular. Here's a [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/tools/juju)